# Get user installed app information [windows phone]

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

i have a code for android below

```
List<PackageInfo> PackList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i=0; i < PackList.size(); i++)
{
    PackageInfo PackInfo = PackList.get(i);
    if ( ( (PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true)
    {
        String AppName = PackInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        Log.e("App" + Integer.toString(i), AppName);
    }
}
```

above code gets the information of user installed apps.
So my question is simple how to achieve same functionality in windows phone (Native or Hybrid any one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.There is no such communication existing in the present versions. 
Having access to this information would be a potential data privacy issue.
This functionality isn't available for 3rd party apps on Windows Phone 7. You can pass along data using app2app functionality(available only for wp8) (Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) link).

as far as I know You can only get a list of apps on the phone that are published by you.  You do not have access to a complete list of apps on the phone.

Comment: 'published by me' you means installed by me or else?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code to retrieve information about all packages installed across all users.

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackages();
```

[reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj207250.aspx)